# Moq how determine a method was called with a list containing certain values

Tags: c#, moq

Hi say I have a method with the following signature:

```
public void GeneratePaymentAdvise(IList<int> paymentIds)
```

and this is called by another method:

```
public void UpdatePaymentStatus(IList<int> paymentIds, IPaymentLogic paymentLogic)
{
 ...
   paymentLogic.GeneratePaymentStatus(paymentIds);
 ...
}
```

So in a unit test I want to make sure this was called. Using moq:

```
var mockPaymentLogic = new Mock<PaymentLogic>();

UpdatePaymentStatus(new List<int> { 2, 3 }, mockPaymentLogic.Object);

mockPaymentLogic.Verify(x => x.GeneratePaymentStatus(It.IsAny<IList<int>>());
```

So this would work fine and checks that GeneratePaymentStatus is called but only that was called with any old list of ints.

Is there a way to rewrite this so it tests that GeneratePaymentStatus was called with a list of ints containing 2 and 3?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Something like that:

```
mockPaymentLogic.Verify(x => x.GeneratePaymentStatus(It.Is<IList<int>>(l => l.Contains(2) && l.Contains(3))));
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use the same int array for verification.? Something like this..

```
[TestClass]
public class SomeClassTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void UpdatePaymentStatus_PaymentIds_VerifyPaymentLogicGeneratePaymentStatus() {
        var mock = new Mock<IPaymentLogic>();
        var sut = new Sut();
        var idList = new List<int> {2, 3};

        sut.UpdatePaymentStatus(idList, mock.Object);

        mock.Verify(x => x.GeneratePaymentStatus(idList));
    }
}

public class Sut {
    public void UpdatePaymentStatus(IList<int> paymentIds, IPaymentLogic paymentLogic) {
        paymentLogic.GeneratePaymentStatus(paymentIds);
    }
}

public interface IPaymentLogic {
    void GeneratePaymentStatus(IList<int> paymentIds);
}
```

If you verify against a different list other than idList, the test would fail.