# Moq Setup with function that accepts a list of objects, how to define object Ids that can be accepted?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have the below Moq service. One of the functions accepts various parameters but one of them is a `List<MyObject>` where `MtObject` has an `Id`. I have tried to define the actual object that the Moq should accept in order to return what I want returned for that object but it doesn't work - nothing is being returned - I'm wondering if it is because the object supplied isn't the exact object used when we call the Moq service - so I was going to try specifying the `MyObject.Id` in the setup but I can't figure out how to do it.

This was my original:

```
myService.Setup(s => s.GetSomeStuff(
    It.IsAny<Reference>(),
    new List<MyObject>() { fakeMyObject1, fakeMyObject2 },
    anotherThing,
    number))
.Returns(MyResponse).Verifiable();
```

The above returns `null`, if I use `It.IsAny<List<MyObject>>()` then I get a response but I need to have a different response based on the `MyOject` passed in.

What would I replace this line with in order to specify the `fakeObject1.Id` and `fakeObject2.Id` rather than the object?

```
new List<MyObject>() { fakeMyObject1, fakeMyObject2 }
```

Or do you think the original solution should work? Or is there another alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm wondering if it is because the object supplied isn't the exact object used when we call the Moq service

That is correct. Because the argument instances do not match the mock wont behave as desired.

Use the `It.Is<T>()` argument matcher with a predicate to match the desired Ids

```
 myService.Setup(_ => _.GetSomeStuff(
    It.IsAny<Reference>(),
    It.Is<List<MyObject>>(x => 
        x.Any(y => y.Id == fakeObject1.Id || y.Id == fakeObject2.Id) //<-- or something else
    ),
    anotherThing,
    number))
.Returns(MyResponse)
.Verifiable();
```

Reference [Moq Quickstart: Matching Arguments](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#matching-arguments)

Comment: Awesome - exacty what I needed. Started to look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/17144636/1768592 which I couldn't edit to what I needed - yours was a good example